# Examples of creating a simple COM component using C++ in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, com, marshalling, callback

Does anyone know of any recent examples of how to create a simple COM component in C++ using Visual Studio 2008 so I can learn how to marshal different kinds of data between unmanaged and managed code, and back again. I've found a few tutorials that suggest a C++ ATL project, but project settings page no longer has the settings mentioned in the article.

What I want to do is implement a C++ DLL that would be used from C# like this:

```
MyComComponent myComp = new MyComComponent();
myComp.Register(new ClassWithCallbacks()) /* implements IMyCallback */
```

The COM component would, at timed intervals, call various methods on the provided IMyCallback instance to obtain information. Similarly, the C# code might call various methods directly, when needed.

This mechanism is to enable an application to be monitored either by (the C++ side) polling the C# side, or by the C# side reporting back to the C++ side.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from [Walkthrough: Creating a COM Server Using Text Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wad1c0e(VS.80).aspx). It shows how to do it using COM attributes instead of an IDL, but for your purposes this should be sufficient.

If you want more ATL samples, the [ATL General Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cwh50w84(v=VS.80).aspx) section has bunch of samples that implement various COM features, both as in-proc or out-of-proc server, and using IDL instead of attributes. You can download any of them and tweak it to your purposes. I'd probably start with the [BEEPER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b2yx6ttb(v=VS.80).aspx).

Meanwhile, [Interoperating With Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k(v=VS.71).aspx) has a lot of information about the managed side, especially when it comes to more advanced stuff like custom marshaling, events, etc.